# Sweet Alert en PHP y mostrar en el Index.php

Tags: php, sweetalert

estoy intentando reemplazar las alertas normales del navegador por una de Sweet Alert, más sin embargo las alertas normales luego de validar una condición en una función que se encuentra en un archivo diferente al index.php, pero que ya se encuentra vinculado mediante `require_once "";` me recarga la pagina y me muestra la alerta, el contenido de mi pagina no aparece hasta no cerrar la alerta. Muestro imagen como queda.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta que no doy en aceptar no me termina de cargar la pagina... Quisiera que mi contenido no desaparezca mientras se muestra la alerta.

Ya incluí el script de Sweet Alert a mi proyecto en el index, hice una prueba en consola de como quiero que aparezca en mi index la alerta luego de validar la condición en mi otro archivo el cual llamé funciones.php. Desde la consola haciendo la prueba...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intenté reemplazar el código de la alerta normal en la pagina funciones.php pero cuando valida la condición no me muestra ninguna alerta cuando debería mostrarla. Agradezco si me pueden ayudar acerca de como lo hago, he estado buscando hasta ahora no encuentro como hacerlo.

Actualmente tengo el siguiente código.

```
function operacion(){

   if (condicion) {
      sentencias a ejecutar si la condicion se cumple... 
   } else {
     echo "<script>
            Swal.fire({
              icon: 'error',
              title: 'Oops...!',
              text: 'Operación inválida, el puesto ya ha sido vendido.',  
              })
             window.location= 'index.php'
    </script>"; 
  }
}
```

Mas sin embargo no se me ejecuta la alerta...

Al revisar la consola estoy teniendo el siguiente error, "index.php:30 Uncaught ReferenceError: Swal is not defined at index.php:30"; si entro a ver el error por la consola me muestra esto...
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En esa linea es donde tengo la apertura de mi etiqueta PHP en el index....

Comment: si deseas levantar la alerta despues de cargar todas la pagina te propongo echo "<script> $(function(){  
            Swal.fire({
              icon: 'error',
              title: 'Oops...!',
              text: 'Operación inválida, el puesto ya ha sido vendido.',  
              })
             window.location= 'index.php' });
    </script>"; aunque incrustar el codigo javascript dentro del html no me parece una buena idea.

Comment: Gracias @EdelRojas por su comentario, ya he logrado solucionar el problema, enseguida publico la respuesta a la pregunta diciendo como logré solucionarlo..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias a Dios he encontrado la raíz del problema y he logrado solucionar la falla. El problema radicaba en que estaba vinculando el repositorio (creo que así se llama), de Sweet Alert2 en la parte final de mi documento antes de la etiqueta de cierre.

Encontré esto en la web y decidí implementarlo en mi proyecto, vinculando los archivos tanto JS como los CSS de Sweet Alert pero en el Head de mi documento Index.

https://github.com/realrashid/sweet-alert/issues/3.

De tal forma entonces que el inicio de mi código quedó de tal forma.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Mi titulo de Proyecto</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/6.6.9/sweetalert2.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@10"></script>
</head>
```

Con esto logré solucionar mi falla.